# How do I create a .js file that creates a navigation bar in html

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so, I am creating this site and I want every page to have a navigation bar, how do I make it so that instead of having to write the html for the navigation bar on every page, I just write in the .js file and add this javascript file to every page.

Btw, I'm not asking how to write a navigation bar in html, I've already done that.

Comment: This example writes "Hello World!" into an HTML element with ```id="hello"```.  ```<script>
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
</script>```    You can find more examples here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_scripts.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.insertAdjacentHTML` and pass the `'afterbegin'` as the "where" to add the `html`. In this example it's appending as the first element in the body.

```js
const header= "<div>This is my nav</div>"
document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", header);
```

```html
<body>
<div>
 Content of page
<div>
</body>
```

**Edit**  to add links you can do something like:

- add anchor tags `<a>` to each link of your nav
- get the pathname from the url `window.location.pathname`
- query the DOM for `[href='${path}']` (where path is the pathname)
- add the class (in this case `active`) to reflect the current page
- style active class appropriately

**NOTE:**  the current window (stackoverflow snippet window) pathname is `/js` so for this example I used it as the `href` of the second nav link.

**ALSO NOTE:** I'm assuming all your html files are in the same directory

```js
//get the pathname from the current url
const path = window.location.pathname

const header= `
   <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js">Javascript</a></li>
   </ul>`
   
document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", header);

//add the active class to the anchor tag with the href === path
document.querySelector(`[href='${path}']`).classList.add('active')
```

```css
.nav li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.nav .active{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
 Content of page
<div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, now how would I add links to this navigation bar

Comment: I edited to add an example for links

Answer (score 1):

For that, I would recommend that you use a UI library like React, which when paired with React Router will definately yeild you much cleaner code and a better development experience overall.

With that in mind, I know that there is a significant learning curve towards dominating new libs/frameworks, so one way you could do it using vanilla HTML, CSS and JS is by pasting your HTML code for the header into a variable and injecting it by using some DOM methods like .append or .insertAdjecentHTML on a selected element (div, header, body...).

Answer (score 0):

If your site will contain mostly static content, then I suggest looking into a static site generator (SSG) like Jekyll, Hugo or Gatsby. When I started web development, I used Jekyll and it was very beginner friendly. You could then link from your navbar to your other pages normally.